# VS10 Generate Release Build from Debug Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, configuration, build, release

We have a large solution here, with several dozen projects. The only build configuration which has been maintained is the Debug. When switching to release, I get over 300 error messages, mainly:

`"Error  The type or namespace name 'XXX' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\TFS\...\SomeClass.cs"`

and a few

`"Error Metadata file 'C:\TFS\...\some.dll' could not be found SomeProject"`

Is there a way to take the debug configuration completely, and generate a working release one? Preferably automatically/script based, to be done by build server for each release? Most projects are C#, with one or two in C++ or Managed C++ (these dont throw errors).

Comment: Did You check whether same projects are checked in Configuration Manager for both Debug and Release configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that those errors are coming from not building all the projects in the Release configuration?

Check this trough the Configuration Manager and see if all projects are selected to build for the Release configuration.

You can also create a new configuration and then select a configuration to inherit the settings from. Maybe you can create a copy of your debug configuration this way?

For automating a build, you can always use a combination of Powershell and MSBuild to script your build. If you have Team Foundation Server you can use TFS automated builds and publish them to a specified location.

Comment: The projects checked in configuration manager are the same.. Only difference is really just the release-debug switch on every project.

I will try to create a new configuration from debug, but wouldn't it mean that I would need to go through all projects and make sure the compiler settings are set correctly?

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason then why release is not working. Could you elaborate on the errors you get? Have you already tried cleaning your whole solution and rebuilding?

Comment: Looking deeper - in our debug configuration, all build pathes were changed. these are all wrong for release